# How to refresh a component on a JDesktopPane

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jinternalframe, jdesktoppane

I've added a "Terminal" that extends JInternalFrame into my JDesktopPane. terminal constructor is like

```
public Terminal(Executable exec)
```

where Executable is an interface that contains the abstract method elab, and I store that instance into a variable. so when I press "OK", I call `exec.elab(String arg)` method. Into my JDesktopPane i've created a `Terminal(new BasicCommands())`. After that creation, with a command, i want to change the instance of my Terminal with `terminal.setExec(new AdvancedCommands())` where AdvancedCommands and BasicCommands are class that implements Executable interface and contains their own elab method. So when I do that I have no warnings or other things, but when i want to call `terminal.setExec(new AdvancedCommands())` to change my elab method, nothing change... How I can do it? I tried with refreshing terminal (revalidate and repaint) but nothing...

How i add keyListener in Terminal class:

```
inputArea.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
            if (arg0.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
                if(!inputArea.getText().isEmpty()){
                    scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum());
                    exec.elab(new Str(inputArea.getText())); //I want to change this method with ter.setExec(some class that implements Executable);
                    clearInputArea();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works, but I don't know if there are others better:

```
public void refresh(){
    revalidate();
    repaint();
    inputArea.removeKeyListener(ad);
    ad = new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
            if (arg0.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
                if(!inputArea.getText().isEmpty()){
                    scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum());
                    exec.elab(new Str(inputArea.getText()));
                    clearInputArea();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    inputArea.addKeyListener(ad);
}
```

I've create this method where I remove my keylistener and add that again.